# Sprite Kit loop multi node background

Tags: iphone, xcode, loops, background, sprite-kit

I am trying to **loop my background image in SK**, the problem is the background is long so I split the image up into **tiles that I paste together with code.** I want to loop this huge background but I don't know how, the **regular methods** of looping backgrounds haven't worked because my background is made up of **multiple nodes.**

This is my method I use to render the nodes together.

```
- (SKNode *) createBackgroundNode
{
// 1
// Create the node
SKNode *backgroundNode = [SKNode node];

// 2
// Go through images until the entire background is built
for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < 20; nodeCount++) {
    // 3
    NSString *backgroundImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background%02d", nodeCount+1];
    SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:backgroundImageName];
    // 4
    node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f);
    node.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, nodeCount*64.0f);
    // 5

    backgroundNode.name =@"background";

    [backgroundNode addChild:node];



}



// 6
// Return the completed background node
return backgroundNode;
}
```

Then Inside my update method, I use this code to move all the tiles at once by moving the **background layers** position in my desired direction.

```
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {


        SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;



        bg.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, -((_player.position.y - 200.0f)/10));



              }];
```

The problem is, I can't get the **size of the background layer** only the position (at least I think I can't) **So I have no idea how I can loop all these tiles seamlessly ?**

I preferably want to do it all in one class but any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ios7 Sprite Kit How to loop image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675146/ios7-sprite-kit-how-to-loop-image)

Comment: Kinda of, I havent had an answer yet so ya know..